# Discriminant of an Elliptic Curves and Good/Bad Reduction

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry, local-field

Here is a remark from Silverman's *Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves*:

[in his notation, $K$ is a number field and $M_K^0$ is the set of non-archimedian  places in $K$]

[image]

How does he know that $v(a_1),...,v(a_6)\geq 0$ and $v(\Delta)=0$ for all but finitely many $v\in M_K^{0}$? And why is this a minimal Weierstrass equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basically because an integer can only have finitely many prime
factors. I'll take $K=\Bbb Q$. Otherwise one has to replace prime factors
by prime ideal factors, but the principle is the same.

One can write $a_i=b_i/c_i$ where $b_i$ and $c_i$ are integers, and $c_i\ne0$. Then $v(c_i)<0$ if $v=v_p$
 with $p$ a prime factor of $c_i$. There are only finitely many such $p$.
Also $\Delta=u/v$ with $u$ and $v$ nonzero integers, and $v(\Delta)\ne0$
only if $v=v_p$ for $p\mid uv$. Again there are only finitely many such $p$.

When the conditions holds, $v(\Delta)=0$ and more-or-less by definition
the equation is minimal Weierstrass **over the field $K_v$.** It
maybe not a minimal Weierstrass equation over the number field $K$.